# Formal "More or less"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Could you please tell me how I could replace "more or less" to make it more formal in the following sentence:

*"Those behaviours are more or less dangerous to them"*

I've been looking for a correct sentence for a while, but it seems that my brain has blown a fuse. Thank you!

Comment: I would cast that sentence as "Those behaviors pose potential dangers to them.".

Comment: The sentence is unclear in the first place. "More or less" can mean"approximately", or "to some extent", or even, "EITHER more OR less dangerous than... [something else already mentioned]". Which one do you mean?

Comment: @ArchContrarian is right. `Approximately` is a good formal synonym for `more or less`. Neither makes much sense in your sentence. Moreover, the plural form of `behavior` sticks out to me. Please clarify what you want to convey.

Comment: Oh right, I suppose I made a wrong translation from my native language (sorry). In that case I suppose I will have to change the entire sentence, but I still don't know how to. I want to convey the idea that behaviours (different kinds of consumer behaviours, that is) can be slightly dangerous or very dangerous.

Comment: 'Those behaviours are _comparatively_ dangerous to them'. 'Those behaviours are _relatively_ dangerous to them.' In my view ,the choice between  'more or less' and my two suggestions are a matter of style and personal opinion.

Comment: Thanks a million @Nigel , I will go for relatively as I think it is the closest to what I was looking for! 

Once again, sorry for the mistranslation. I'll definitely be more careful  of deceptive cognates next time.

Comment: @CmcmA Glad to be of service.

Comment: There is nothing about "more or less" that can't be used in a formal setting. What you seem to be looking for is something that is more pompous.

Comment: more or less ... is perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recast it, but I think formal usage would be:

> Those behaviours are dangerous to them to a greater or lesser extent (or degree)